# elastic: match all tokens in one array member

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index where multiple people can be assigned to one document by their names+roles.
Up until now we implemented searches by adding "person" as nested document and just indexing all related people to one document.

We are not satisfied with query performance and I want to try denormalising the nested documents from

```
"people":{
    {
    "firstName:"Alice",
    "lastName: "Aliceson",
    "role":"admin"
    },
    {
    "firstName:"Bob",
    "lastName: "Bobson",
    "role":"creator"
    }
}
```

to

```
"people": ["Alice Aliceson admin", "Bob Bobson creator"]
```

my issue is, a match query with `and` as operator will still find the document with these people when querying like this

```
"match": {
    "people": {
        "query": "Aliceson Alice creator",
        "operator":"and"
    }
}
```

is there a way to make elastic require matches for all tokens in just ONE array member?

alternatively: can someone point me in a better direction, I cannot find an example for this in the docs or any guides (all guides just use nested, but the docs recommend avoiding nested when tuning for search speed)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays of object

> Arrays of objects do not work as you would expect: you cannot query
>   each object independently of the other objects in the array. If you
>   need to be able to do this then you should use the nested datatype
>   instead of the object datatype.

[From here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html)